# Laravel Stuck with returning a json request -> Integer Array -> receiving Eloquent Models

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel, eloquent

I tried to answer a JSON Request, returning Laravel-Models on the delivered id's in the request.

**This is my - JSON-Request**
`{
    "places": [1,2, 3, 4, 5]
}`

First i transform it to an array:

**Convert Request to Array**

```
$array = $request->places;
```

**Output:**

```
array:5 [
  0 => 1
  1 => 2
  2 => 3
  3 => 4
  4 => 5
]
```

And this is how i would receive all Models (1,2 are the manually entered id's in this example:
**Get all Places**

```
$posts = Post::whereIn('place_id',[1,2] )->get();
```

My Problem, the placeholder [1,2] only allows a list of Integer. But I'm not able to transform my array into the placeholder variable like this.

```
$posts = Post::whereIn('place_id',[$request] )->get();
```

If i put the Array into a String variable, lets say: $request = "1,2,3,4,5"  then, I only receive Models from the first Value (number 1 in this case).

Is there any way to transform my JSON-Requests to receive all Laravel Models?

Any help will be appreciated, 
Cheers Sebastian

Comment: try `$posts = Post::whereIn('place_id', array_values($request->places) )->get();`

Comment: Wouldn't you just do `$posts = Post::whereIn("place_id", $array)->get();`?

Comment: Unfortunatley, there is an "array_values() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given" Error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try something like this.

```
$posts = Post::whereIn('place_id', $request->request->get('places', []))->get();
```

When your request body is.

```
{
    "places": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately there is like an foreach() error: "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"

Comment: @Sebastian Do you send your request with the `Content-Type: application/json` header?

Comment: Yes, i use Content-Type application/json & Accept application/json in my Header.

Comment: It looks like something wrong with your request. Can you provide the output of the `dd($request->request->all())` function call inside your controller action?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, array:1 [
  "place_id" => array:3 [
    0 => "1"
    1 => "2"
    2 => "3"
  ]
]

Comment: Then I filtered the place_Id and now have something like: array:3 [
  0 => "1"
  1 => "2"
  2 => "3"
]